# How often are the Azure Mobile Engagement Analytics reports calculated?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-engagement

In the Monitor -tab the data is almost real time but in Analytics the data seems to be at least a day old.

How often are the Analytics reports calculated and can I speed this up? We have a LOB app so the user count is < 50 so there isn't much data to crunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics are computed once a day.